# problems with jquery tabs on ajax based pages

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

hi i am using jquery tabs on timeline of users for there friends, likes, pages.
The page on which the tabs are located is loading asynchronously. On first time if i select user from side panel(list of users located in left side of main webpage). It works well and if i select tabs on loaded page and after that if i select a new user the tabs are not rendering and also another webpages are not working. For refrence and to know exact problem please visit http://www.funnenjoy.com (login is required).

problems coming in these places like:-

> user login -> dashboard opens->user select one of her friend user from
>   left side panel or by searching no-friend users(if)->friend user's
>   timeline opens containing four tabs(1. about 2. friends 3. images 4.
>   likes) all thing works like charm tabs also works.

now again if without **refreshing page** user select another user like

> dashboard->user select another one of her friend user or non-friend
>   user by searching(asynchronously through suggestion)[if]->friend
>   user's timeline opens but tabs not working renders like li.
>
> also if user select another webpage(not timeline) page jquery ui
>   doesn't work.
>
> **Note:-**  All pages are loading in a container with id 'work_selection'. I also try unbind and empty the div first but
>   doesn't seems to work. Any one please help.

Comment: could you post the jquery for it

Comment: hey now problem solved this was problem of error encountred inside dom before loading these tabs